# is possible to make a ElasticSearch query against a array field that all its elements must satisfy some condition

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I am using ElasticSearch and has a field of number array like below.

```
{
  income: [200, 300, 400]
}
```

I need to write a query to find documents that all elements of their income are greater than a certain value.
for example, if the condition is

```
> 250
```

then the document above should not be hit because 200 is less than 250.
but if the condition is

```
> 150
```

then the document should be returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this via a scripted query that iterates over the array field and check the desired condition.
In the above case following would be the queryDsl

```
GET testample/_search
{
  "query": {
    "script": {
      "script": {
        "source": " boolean test = false; for (inc in doc['income']) { if(params.income<=inc) { test=true; } else { test=false; break;} } return test;",
        "params": {
          "income": 150
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Basically you could have any code executed in the script section. What the above query does is, it takes the user input as the param and then checkes whether it is less than all elements in the array and if yes then the doc evaluates as true and hence is returned as a query response.